# Android: GoogleAnalytics vs EasyTracker

Tags: android, google-analytics, easytracker

I didn't quite got the difference between using

```
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();
```

and

```
Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-XXXX-Y");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between EasyTracker and the regular Tracker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961520/whats-the-difference-between-easytracker-and-the-regular-tracker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EasyTracker` is a class designed to easy the burden of adding Google Analytics tracking code to your application. It runs in single thread.

In short, it is recommended to use `EasyTracker`.

p.s. `EasyTracker` is a subclass of `Tracker`

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration